Variadic template ambiguity
I would like to write a templated function with varidiac tempate parameters. (I do not want a variable number of function parameters). When I try to do it, I get this ambiguity:
#include <iostream>

template<int arg>
int sum()
{
    return arg;
}

template <int d, int... arguments>
int sum()
{
    return d + sum<arguments...>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum<2, 5, 7>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


main.cpp:12:16: error: call to 'sum' is ambiguous    return d + sum<arguments...>();
main.cpp:12:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sum<5, 7>' > requested here
main.cpp:17:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sum<2, 5, 7>' requested here

How do I make this non-ambiguous?

For reference: class templates support pattern matching, but function templates don't. (overloads are their own form of pattern matching).
This is an example where a class template is used: https://godbolt.org/z/zq1rb3e5r
In C++17 and above, a fold expression can also be used, and no matching is needed: https://godbolt.org/z/Wz9hf9cj9
Fold expressions are the recommended solution. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold for reference on how they work

Use only template <int d, int... Is> constexpr int sum() { return (d + ... + Is); } (C++17).

@Jarod42 what is this magic called? I would like to learn how this even works, but I don't know what to google. I see it doesn't recurse, by adding logging, so it must somehow iteratively call operator+ on the types ?

Parameter pack and Fold expression (C++17)
